perf stat for only the process I invoke with it
On Ubuntu, using:
sudo perf stat -e offcore_requests.demand_code_rd,offcore_requests.all_requests,l2_rqsts.all_demand_data_rd,mem_inst_retired.all_loads myApp

I'd like perf to return statistics only for myApp. I know this is possible with -p but that means I have to start the app and then poll the PID and start perf on it.
Is there an option to only sample statistics for myApp and launch it at the same time?

perf stat  ./a.out normally does only count for that process if you don't use -a.  Uncore events (like memory controller stuff) might not be able to distinguish which core, but "offcore" events just count requests made by this core.  Are you sure your command doesn't work?  It's counting kernel work, too, including interrupt handlers, but only while your task is current.  You can use --all-user to program the counters to only increment while the CPU is in user mode.

Thanks. I suspect (but am not sure) that it's aggregating processes because I'm running a microbenchmark I'm writing and the mem_inst_retired.all_loads metric is 10x higher than I expect it to be.

On what CPU?  Most microarchitectures have some errata for their PMUs; it's possible the hardware is mis-counting.  Or of course possible your benchmark doesn't do what you thought.

Both are possible. This is a NUC Intel Core i5 box so I think the counters would be fairly reliable. I'll go ahead and trace my code to see what it's doing.

You haven't answered my question about what CPU model.  i5-what?  There have been about 14 generations of i5 since Nehalem in 2007, most of them with different errata.  (A few microarchitectures like Coffee Lake etc. were all basically identical to Skylake).

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7260U CPU @ 2.20GHz

So I took a disassembly of my program. The main loop does generate the correct number of memory loads. However, perf reports a much higher number (I ran 1.5M loads, perf reports 54M retired loads).
The program is very simple (just loops through accessing an array and accumulating). Can be seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/bh58G5x57

I get 3.2M counts for mem_inst_retired.all_loads (or 2.2M with --all-user) on my Skylake system (i7-6700k), x86-64 Arch Linux, compiled with g++ -O2.  1.5M is a very small amount for a whole process. Startup code (CRT _start which calls glibc init functions) do a significant amount of work in your process before main is reached.  Try looping over the array many thousands of times so your program runs for about a second, so startup overhead is insignificant.

@PeterCordes interesting. What version of g++ and any other flags?

g++ -O2 loadbench.cpp was the entire command.  That's GCC 14.2.1, glibc 2.40+r16.  Like most distros, Arch configures their GCC with -fPIE -pie -fstack-protector-strong on by default.
